# can't displaying combobox value in texbox

Tags: javascript, html, web

i am getting the values from database and showing them in the combobox, Now what i want to show selected combobox value in the text field i tried to solve it but i can't  kindly help me.....here is my code

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="time.php" enctype="multipart/form-      data">
     <table align="center">
     <p>
     <tr><td>
     <label>Depurture</label></td>
     <td>
     <script>
function CBtoTB()
{
document.getElementById("text").value=document.getElementById("ComboBox").value
}
</script>
     <select>
<option id="ComboBox" onchange="CBtoTB()">Select City</option>
<?php 
include ('Database/db.php');

$result=mysql_query("SELECT `ctod` FROM `dewoocandd`") or die(mysql_error());
if($result)
{
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $cname=$row['ctod'];
  echo "<option value=\"$cname\" ";
   echo'SELECTED';
echo "> ";
echo $row['ctod'];
   echo '</option>';
  }

 }

 ?>
 </select></td></tr></td>
    </p>
    <p>

     <tr><td> <label>Time:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="pname" id="text" value="" required></td></tr>
      `enter code here`  </p>



      <tr><td> </td><td align="right"> <input type="submit" name="button" id="button"        value="Submit"></td></tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Does your dropdown bind proper values? can you try it with static values?

Comment: yeah its working with static values

Comment: So, check your Bindings with the dropdown. i am sure you will get the solution

Answer (score 2):

`id="ComboBox"` and `onchange="CBtoTB()"` should be in select tag, not in option tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach your `onchange` event to the `select` element and update the value of the textbox to the value of the `select`.

Javascript:

```
function CBtoTB() {
    document.getElementById("text").value = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="CBtoTB()">
    <option >Select City</option>
    ...
</select>
```